# Can't drag/drop applications to a different desktop

Tags: 10.10, gnome, workspaces

This has been bugging me for a while, and I can't find any preference settings that are affecting it, but:

On one install of Ubuntu/Gnome I've been able to drag applications in the bottom panel across to one of the virtual desktops and it would move there.

However, with the install I'm using on a different computer, it is refusing to do this, and all I can do is right-click and select the desktop.

This has happened on a number of versions of Gnome (from 9.04 through to 10.10) with one computer having this function, and the other computer not. I've also done a couple of complete rebuilds - so it doesn't appear to be a preference/option being stuck somewhere.

Anyone have any clue how to get this functionality enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess and suppose you were using metacity on the older system, and are now using compiz.

Compiz works a bit differently with the GNOME-panel, and you can't drag the applications on the panel to a new workspace. You can however, drag the application by the title bar and move it to the edge of the screen. This will cause the window to change to the next workspace (so long as you have the advanced effects enabled in appearance properties).

Leave me a comment if you need more detail.

EDIT:
You will also need [compiz config](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2756/ubuntu_install_compiz_config_settings_manager_configure_desktop_effects/) to enable dragging windows across desktops.
Desktop wall (or cube if you like) provide the option. In desktop wall for example:
[image]
The option is edge_flip_move. You can also you edge_flip_dnd for drag and drop :)

Comment: Ah, okay - I get the metacity/compiz thing. I tried setting the advanced visual effects as you said, but while I got the stretchy window effect when dragging them, I couldn't move it to another desktop still... maybe I need to restart?

Comment: restart didn't make a difference

Comment: my mistake I forgot you need to enable that as an option.